# Do not replace the second occurrence of pattern in a same word in the file with sed command

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

```
echo "abcdef12cade 12345678 abcdefba12345678" | sed -E "s/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/00000000/g"
```

the above outputs the following

```
00000000cade 00000000 0000000000000000
```

it is replacing the pattern for second occurrence in a same word.
I don't want to replace if there is a second occurrence.

expected ouput

```
00000000cade 00000000 abcdefba12345678
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to replace the first occurrence of a match, don't use the `g` suffix to the command:

```
$ echo 'aa' | sed 's/a/b/g'
bb
$ echo 'aa' | sed 's/a/b/'
ba
```

The `g` option stands for 'global', which is explicitly telling `sed` to replace all matches and not just the first (which is the default behavior).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking for words that are between 8 and 15 chars, and replace the first 8 hex digits:

```
sed -E 's/\<[[:xdigit:]]{8}([[:xdigit:]]{0,7})\>/00000000\1/g' <<END
abcdef12cade 12345678 abcdefba12345678 12345 123456789
END
```

```
00000000cade 00000000 abcdefba12345678 12345 000000009
```

Where, `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries, and `[:xdigit:]` matches a hex digit.

Answer (score 1):

The `g` at the end make `sed` repeat the substitution as many times as possible on the line.  You only want to do it twice.

Let's do that with GNU `awk`:

```
echo 'abcdef12cade 12345678 abcdefba12345678' |
awk '{ sub("[0-9a-fA-F]{8}", "00000000", $1)
       sub("[0-9a-fA-F]{8}", "00000000", $2)
       print }'
```

This performs the substitution on the two first whitespace-delimited fields only, and then prints the resulting line.

Comment: OP _didn't_ want the second match replaced though?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Their expected output is `00000000cade 00000000 abcdefba12345678`, which is what this produces.

Comment: @DopeGhoti ... and I didn't read the title of the question until now, which leaves me more than slightly confused.

Comment: Yeah, the actual prose, title, and expected output presented are all somewhat contadictory.