# Replace hex eight digits only, ignore if less than or more than 8 digits together. Using sed command

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

Example:

---

Input:

```
0x12345678 0aef1234 0098adefa 123456789
```

Expected Output:

```
0x00000000 00000000 0098adefa 123456789
```

---

Tried this:

```
sed -E "s/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/00000000/g"
```

But this replaces even if there are more than 8 continues hex digits.

Comment: Very nearly a dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451130

Answer (score 5):

You can use word boundary `\b` to mark the beginning or the end of a word, and additionally one needs to take into account that the `0x` is possible in front of the number:

```
sed -E 's/\b(0x|)[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b/\100000000/g'
```

Still, there are special cases which you need to think through what to do with them,  like `00x12345678`, in the above pattern it is not replaced.

Comment: @NicHartley: `sed` supports `?` without extended regular expressions, but it must be escaped with a backslash: for instance, `sed -e 's/a\?b/'`.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, you can use the "look-around assertions", i.e. you can say "not preceded by a hexdigit" and "not followed by a hexdigit":

```
perl -pe 's/(?<![0-9a-fA-F])[0-9a-fA-F]{8}(?![0-9a-fA-F])/00000000/g'
```

The look-arounds don't count into the matched string, i.e. they aren't replaced and they can match more than once (once in the look-behind and once in the look-ahead).

You can also use the `[:xdigit:]` POSIX class instead of `0-9a-fA-F`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '0x12345678 0aef1234 0098adefa 123456789' | sed -E 's/(\<|x)[[:xdigit:]]{8}\>/\100000000/g'
0x00000000 00000000 0098adefa 123456789

$ echo '12345678 0aef1234 0098adefa 123456789' | sed -E 's/(\<|x)[[:xdigit:]]{8}\>/\100000000/g'
00000000 00000000 0098adefa 123456789
```

The regular expression

```
(\<|x)[[:xdigit:]]{8}\>
```

will match a hexadecimal number that is eight digits long. It should be a complete word, or be preceded by an `x`.  The preceding character (the `x`, if there is one) is saved and inserted before the zeros in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks. Command is working as expected except for first word. For input: "12345678 0x12345678 abcd12345"   the output is "12345678 0x00000000 abcd12345" it did not replace first word though 8 digit hex. Expected Output: "00000000 0x00000000 abcd12345"

Comment: @HidayathullahKhan There was no indication in the question that input on that format was expected. You should add that there.

Comment: @HidayathullahKhan I have taken this into account now.